# Event OnLoad on Telerik's grid (client selection)

Tags: telerik

I'm using Grid with "Client Selection" (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc-beta/grid/selectionclientside) of Telerik, and my page loads with one of the lines already marked. I wonder how it could activate the event OnRowSelected (on the marked line) when the page loads.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/client-side-row-select.aspx) forum thread.

Answer (score 0):

Go look at the "Controller (example)" tab with the code. In the `ActionResult _SelectionClientSide_Orders(string customerID)` method you see the line that says `customerID = customerID ?? "ALFKI";`. This is essentially an `if customerID is null, set it to "ALFKI"` statement. Based on that, the initial row is selected. So this is actually done server-side rather than client-side.